# How to forbid users to change their first, last and screen names?

Tags: php

I'm using Wordpress 3.1. I need to forbid users to change their first, last and screen names in their profile, but admin must still have this possibility. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question - Preventing users from changing their email address](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/prevent-users-from-changing-their-email-address).

Comment: I've added `<?php if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) print ('disabled="disabled"') ?>` to input tags.

Comment: @post-factum it wont save if you would submit a post request.

Comment: @ilovewordpress But it works for me.